# Check if vector item not null C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have structure:

```
struct node
{
    bool data;
    node* l;
    node* r;
    node(bool data_) : data(data_), l(0), r(0) {}
};
```

And loop like this

```
void printNode(std::vector<node*> nodes, int level, int max_level)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        node * itr = nodes.at(i);
        if (itr->data != 2) {
            cout << itr->data;
            newNodes.push_back(itr->l);
            newNodes.push_back(itr->r);
        } else {
            newNodes.push_back(new node(2));
            newNodes.push_back(new node(2));
            cout << " ";
        }

        printWhitespaces(betweenSpaces);
    }
}
```

Some times itr->l(or r) is null, not init struct. How i can check this ?

Comment: Why are you passing 2 as a bool?

Comment: @Foon - it means **really** true.

Comment: you should not hold a raw pointer in a vector. Use a standard smart ptr, such as unique_ptr, or shared_ptr. unique_ptr is the better choice, less overhead, just make sure to std::move the nodes into the vector.

Comment: Or just be smart and meticulous when managing your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? It will skip your `NULL` elements, and elements with `NULL` value for `r` member of the `vector` and continue the `for` loop.

```
node * itr = nodes.at(i);
if(!itr || !itr->r) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a pointer is null simply use:

```
itr->l == 0
```

If it is 0 it is null. But consider using smart pointers, they are much safer.

You should also considering iterating over your vector the standard way, using something like this:

```
std::vectoc<node*>::iterator
    it = nodes.begin(),
    ite = nodes.end();
for(; it != ite; ++it) {
    ...
}
```

And finally you should probably be passing your vector by reference like this:

```
void printNode(std::vector<node*>& nodes, int level, int max_level)
```